# AWS EKS Fargate - Unable to mount EFS volume with statefulset

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to run a statefulSet in AWS EKS Fargate and attach a EFS volume with it, but I am getting errors in mounting a volume with pod.
These are the error I am getting from describe pod.

```
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From               Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----               -------
  Normal   LoggingEnabled  114s               fargate-scheduler  Successfully enabled logging for pod
  Normal   Scheduled       75s                fargate-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/app1 to fargate-10.0.2.123
  Warning  FailedMount     43s (x7 over 75s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "efs-pv" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not mount "fs-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:/" at "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/b799a6d6-fe9e-4f80-ac2d-8ccf8834d7c4/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/efs-pv/mount": mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t efs -o tls fs-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b799a6d6-fe9e-4f80-ac2d-8ccf8834d7c4/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/efs-pv/mount
Output: Failed to resolve "fs-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct, and ensure that the VPC has an EFS mount target for this file system ID.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/efs/mount-dns-name for more detail.
Attempting to lookup mount target ip address using botocore. Failed to import necessary dependency botocore, please install botocore first.
Warning: config file does not have fall_back_to_mount_target_ip_address_enabled item in section mount.. You should be able to find a new config file in the same folder as current config file /etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.conf. Consider update the new config file to latest config file. Use the default value [fall_back_to_mount_target_ip_address_enabled = True].
```

If anyone has setup efs volume with eks fargate cluster please have a look at it. I am really stucked in from long time.

What I have setup

- Created a EFS Volume
- CSIDriver Object

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CSIDriver
metadata:
  name: efs.csi.aws.com
spec:
  attachRequired: false
```

- Storage Class

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
```

- PersistentVolume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: <EFS filesystem ID>
```

- PersistentVolumeClaim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

- Pod Configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app1 
    image: busybox 
    command: ["/bin/sh"] 
    args: ["-c", "while true; do echo $(date -u) >> /data/out1.txt; sleep 5; done"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: persistent-storage
      mountPath: /data
  volumes:
  - name: persistent-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: efs-claim
```

Comment: `Failed to resolve "fs-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct, and ensure that the VPC has an EFS mount target for this file system ID.` - what actions have you taken for this?

Comment: @gohm'c I have already verified efs id, mount targets are already there with security groups with required permissions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you literally a day after and have been working on the error nonstop since then! Did you check to make sure your VPC had DNS hostnames enabled? That is what fixed it for me.

Just an FYI, if you are using fargate and you want to change this--I had to go as far as deleting the entire cluster after changing the DNS hostnames flag in order for the change to propagate. I'm unsure if you're familiar with the DHCP options of a normal ec2 instance, but usually it takes something like renewing the ipconfig in order to force the flag to propagate, but since fargate is a managed system, I was unable to find a way to do so from the node itself. I have created *another* post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375071/how-to-propagate-dns-hostnames-network-changes-and-or-role-changes-inside-aws) attempting to answer *that* question.

Another quick FYI: if your pod execution role doesn't have access to EFS, you will need to add a policy that allows access (I just used the default AmazonElasticFileSystemFullAccess Role for the time being in order to try to get things working). Once again, you will have to relaunch your whole cluster in order to get this role change to propagate if you haven't already done so!