# How to Propagate DNS Hostnames (Network Changes), and/or Role Changes Inside AWS EKS using Fargate without Relaunching the Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, paas

As the title suggests, I am unable to propagate Role, or any "Network" changes (AKA: Changing VPC DNS hostname flag to "Enabled" without deleting the entire cluster and relaunching.

Usually in order to propagate these changes in EC2 or normal EKS (without fargate) I simply restart the server or node, respectively. With Fargate, this is not possible considering one doesn't have access to the underlying nodes. Is there a certain way to send commands to the node itself, or at least force a restart on the node in order to make these changes? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Is there a certain way to send commands to the node itself, or at least force a restart on the node in order to make these changes?`

You can try `kubectl rollout restart deployment <name>` to redeploy pods that runs on Fargate; which will cause Fargate to re-allocate your pods.